# Laptop gliches when temperature rises to 45C

Tags: dram

My apologies if the question in not appropriate for the community, however I've read one theoretical one here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13873/why-exactly-do-chips-start-malfunctioning-once-they-overheat and my question is related IMHO.

And on forum for laptop brand I found topic with similar problem but posters argue about not getting it replaced under warranty and costs, not about technical staff.

I want to pinpoint failure point in Laptop with soldered memory. Memory check consistently starts to give errors at about 3 min run time when CPU temperature rises (reportedly by Memtest) to about 45C regardless of memory range tested (I tried to target each of 4 memory banks - afaik there are 4 in that model). Small range makes full one error-free pass (it lasted about 2 min), errors on second one. I know CPU in that Laptop uses main memory for graphics, if it matters. I tested computer giving it several hours to cool off between tests.

As all memory banks respond similarly, I can suspect they all gone back due to some overheating maybe that happened sometime ago. Or could this be a problem in CPU or elsewhere? How could I test that (preferable without taking laptop apart because memory is soldered and I don't have similar CPU for a change)?

EDIT: running only one test - addressing lasted more than 15 minutes with CPU temp trailing at 43-45C. At 6th min there was single error (10 errors at one address 20000) than run for more than 10 min w/out errors but instead of usual screen freeze screen suddenly became gray.

Comment: 45C is a very low temperature to be having any noticeable effect whatsoever on a computer.  Do you have a temperature probe, thermal camera or a non conductive liquid with a low evaporation point available to trace thermal problems?(I think rubbing alcohol is normally used)

Comment: If you're trying to fix a newer mac(I'm unaware of other companies soldering ram) you may just be SOL, but you could check out Louis Rossman's apple laptop repair videos on youtube.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the memory controller, not the memory itself. In any case, repair/usage questions are off-topic here.

Comment: It's Lenovo, K H. BTW somehow K H is not clickable, I don't see how to add that name to my reply, why is that? What is SOL, I could not find meaning using web search.

Comment: @Dave Tweed, is there site in stackex for repair? As you I assume can see I started my question in electronics.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov SOL =  Sadly Outta Luck (polite form)